# Border around a range of cells in a sorted WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a horizontal `ListBox` of items, each of which has two properties: **Name**, and **Parent**. Several items have the same Parent, and some items have no parent.

I would like to present the list with items ordered by Parent if they have one, otherwise by Name. That will leave us with a list similar to the following (**Parent** represented as letter, **Name** as digit):

```
 1   A1   A2   C1   C2   C3   2   3
```

Now I would like to put a border around each group of `ListItems` belonging to each parent, like so:

```
    /-A-----\  /-C----------\
1   |A1   A2|  |C1   C2   C3|  2   3   
    \-------/  \------------/
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you might be able to use a [`CollectionView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) to group the items and then specify a [`GroupStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx) to draw borders around groups, if the documentation does not provide enough information for you to work with i might be able to help out, but not now.

Comment: That's the only way that I can think to do that too.

Comment: In practice, that theory works perfectly - just set up a `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle` that applies a template to the `GroupItem` which wraps a border around the `ItemsPresenter`. Good call.

Comment: One potential tricky bit is that items with *no* group are collected into their own group, which makes maintaining the order as shown in my question difficult. Doesn't matter enough to me at the moment to find a workaround, though.

Comment: Thinking about this for a bit that seems like an interesting problem of its own. Possibly one could get something done by create a custom GroupDescription which assigns parentless items to unique groups but then the groups need to convery information to the group-style whether there should be a border or not.